# How does the YARN container use the allocated CPU?

Tags: jvm, containers, hadoop-yarn

I am struggling to understand how yarn containers are limited to allocated resources, especially the CPU.

I am running Spark or Flink jobs in the YARN cluster. Each executor or task manager requests a yarn container that has 1 CPU. Basically, the number of containers is equal to the number of CPUs available in the host.

I understand that YARN monitors the memory usage, and if the container exceeds the limit, it sends a kill signal. I am wondering about how CPU scheduling really works.

My JVM job in the YARN container(1CPU) can try to create multiple CPU-bound work threads. Will JVM be limited to 1 CPU core to execute those threads, or will it steal resources from other containers? Can technically a YARN container affect other containers' CPU performance?

Let's say I have 10 CPU in the host and I created a single container. Will that containers CPU performance be 10% of the host CPU performance?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, yarn only allocates resources by RAM.  so by default it hopes everyone plays nicely and you can get affected by CPU hungry jobs.  You can change this:

[From Apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setting_up_ResourceManager_to_use_CapacityScheduler):

> yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator   The ResourceCalculator
> implementation to be used to compare Resources in the scheduler. The
> default i.e.
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator only
> uses Memory while DominantResourceCalculator uses Dominant-resource to
> compare multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc. A Java
> ResourceCalculator class name is expected.

In general it's enough to estimate by Memory.  Most people actually estimate they're requirements for memory and threads very poorly.  It's usually best to ignore [threads] unless you encounter issues.  If it maintains to be an issue then maybe consider looking at DominantResourceCalculator.  If/when you turn on resourceDominantCalculator be ready for a lot of people to feel the impact.  You may have grossly over allocated threads and when we start counting threads, they will suddenly have to account for what they've asked for.  (Or at least this was my experience.)  This could grossly appear to shrink capacity of your cluster as space is reserved where it wasn't before.

TLDF: Don't touch this unless you have a good reason. (Wait until it's a problem, don't optimize until there is a bottleneck ).  Users can make innocent mistakes in their resource estimation and it can be painful to grow their ability to correctly estimate what they need.

Comment: I already use DominantResourceCalculator. I don't have a problem with resource allocation. What I wonder is how the CPU is isolated among containers. Can a container use different containers CPUs? Does YARN automatically handle cgroups like Docker? In Focker, my container cannot use more than what is allocated.

Comment: Yarn does use cgroups to enforce policies.

Comment: Does it automatically do that during launching the container or is it something that should be enabled?

Comment: You can likely view this yourself by looking into the container logs and examine the log.  I know I've seen it kill containers for running out of memory and to find out why I normally look at the container logs.  That's how I know it uses cgroups, as the application log will only report the container was killed.